# Expanding pattern twice for dependency

Tags: c, makefile

Is it possible to expand `%` twice for a dependency name?

I have project split into several sections, where each section is in it's own folder and file of the same name, e.g.

`sections/first/first.c`,`sections/hello/hello.c`, etc.

Now I would like to build for each section a target in another folder `build`; I've come up with the following

```
SECTIONS = $(wildcard sections/*/*.c)
TARGETS = $(addprefix build/,$(notdir $(SECTIONS)))

$(TARGETS): build/%.c: sections/%/%.c
    # do something
```

The problem however is that `%` is expanded only once, so I end up with an error

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'sections/first/%.c', needed by 'build/first.o'.
```

Is there a way to expand `%` twice?

Comment: But what would % expand to the second time? Do you really want it to expand to 'sections/first/first.c'? Does every file below sections live in a directory with the same name as the basename of the file name? You might want to use the vpath directive to search all directories below sections. Example: `vpath build/%.c $(dir $(SECTIONS))`

Comment: Yes the name is same (as stated in the beginning) so I want % to expand to the same string. But I'll take a look at the `vpath`

Comment: That's not possible. Try to reorganize your source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to get the `%` to expand more than one time.  If you need this you'll have to do something more fancy: you can use either [secondary expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) or `eval`.  For example, this should work:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(TARG) : build/%.c : source/$$*/$$*.c
        @echo copy $< $@
```

For more in-depth discussion you can check [these blog posts](http://make.mad-scientist.net/category/metaprogramming/).

Comment: Just a general comment (the solution you give seems the cleanest one in this case): an alternative to `eval` is always to generate and then `include` a sub-Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

```
SECTIONS = $(wildcard sections/*)

.PHONY: all

all: $(SECTIONS)
    $(foreach dir,$(SECTIONS), \
    ( cd $d && $(MAKE) -f ../makefile.bot name=$(dir) all ); )
```

Where the above is in a top level makefile
and a second makefile (in this case `makefile.bot`) performs the actual work.

a similar rule as the `all` rule for clean  install,etc would be in the top level makefile, but the target would be changed from `all` to `clean`, etc

The makefile.bot would use `$name` to set the executable name, etc

Notice the use of the parens around the `cd` and `make -f ...` so those commands are run in a 'new' shell so when the `make` exits, execution is in the original top level directory and ready to loop to do it all again in the next directory.